# VCS Labelling in TeamCity while overriding a template

Tags: teamcity, build-automation

We use TeamCity and Subversion for build management.
For each project, we have multiple build configurations, one for each environment we will deploy to (e.g. Dev, Test, Staging).

It makes sense, I think, to use a TeamCity Template to keep these configurations in sync, overriding the differences with parameters and variables (e.g. overriding NAnt targets).

The problem is that I cannot override the VCS Labelling configurations (the options are greyed out in the build configuration attached to a template). Ideally I'd like only the builds going to Test and Staging to be tagged, not the Dev builds.

Is there a way I can achieve this, or am I going to have to abandon the Template idea and have multiple build configurations?

I'm using TeamCity 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not implemented yet. You should probably vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-15182 request.

Comment: That's a shame.  This is literally the only reason I can't use templates.